# Error in Axis2 Test Client

Tags: java, apache-axis

I created an Axis2 client to test my axis2 webservice. However, i am getting the below error at runtime:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize
 class com.sample.LoginRequestDocument
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.j
ava:517)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(
OutInAxisOperation.java:371)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisO
peration.java:417)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(Out
InAxisOperation.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:
165)
        at com.sample.sampleStub.login(sampleStub.java:4543)
```

any idea how i can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there is a class missing on the server side.  Are you sure that your server side module includes "com.sample.LoginRequestDocument" in its deployment?

Comment: Hi, 
com.sample.LoginRequestDocument class is in the .aar file that I deployed in my resin server but it seems like axis2 or my test client cannot see it

Comment: @Pink - I'm not sure what a .aar file is, but it still looks like this error is on the server.  Perhaps write a simple .jsp and see if the .jsp can see the class?